# How to make an animation to return from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-navigation

The scheme is this in the MainActivity FragmentContainerView, which starts the MainFragment, in which the BottomNavigationView, ViewPager2 and three fragments, I need to click on the button on one of the fragments to switch to another fragment (not from this trio), while the animation of its appearance should be right to left and on top of the current screen with BottomNavigationView and ViewPager2, I did this like this:

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
   android:name="com.example.test.ui.MainFragment">
   <action
      android:id="@+id/navMain_toNavNext"
      app:destination="@id/navigation_next"
      app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_left"
      app:exitAnim="@anim/wait_anim" />
</fragment>
```

wait_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"/>
```

This part works well. But when returning from a fragment, the current one also leaves well from left to right, it doesn’t work for me.

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/navigation_next"
   android:name="com.example.test.ui.NextFragment"
   tools:layout="@layout/fragment_next">
   <action
      android:id="@+id/navNext_toNavHome"
      app:destination="@id/navigation_main"
      app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_right"
      app:exitAnim="@anim/wait_anim"
      app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_left" />
</fragment>
```

slide_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

I tried to set it differently, and rewrite the animations themselves, still nothing comes out, either the animation does not work out, or it works out but at the same time it blinks, or it works out incorrectly. Please tell me what can be done.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't also setting the `popExitAnim`? You really need to set all four if you want both directions to work.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i tried that as well, but result still the same